# Windows 10 Iot Core Will Not Boot

Tags: boot-issues, windows-iot

Issue: Windows 10 IOT Core won't boot past the rainbow-pixel screen on the Raspberry Pi

Currently using:

- proper power supply, 5v - 2.1A
- SanDisk Ultra 16GB SD
- Raspberry Pi model 3B+ (~1 month old)

---

Things I've tried:

- adding a delay in the config.txt file
- changing SD Cards
- installing through NOOBS
- downloading and installing through IOT Core Dashboard
- downloading iso, installing through IOT Core Dashboard
- different power supply
- Normal and insider preview builds
- flashing cards from different computers
- booting w/ and w/o HDMI and peripherals plugged in
- Waiting on rainbow pixel screen for long time

all yield the same result.
The same pi, power supply, and SD Card have successfully run Raspbian in the past

My end goal for this project is to hook up a 3D printer at my office to the network.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

### Updated:

Overtime a lot changes have been happened, this means the Original Answer might now works for newer images. There fore the work around is

1. Download and install [Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/downloads)
2. Insert your SD card and start the dashboard
   [image]
   [image]
3. Take SD card and insert it in your Rassberry Pi
   [image]

### Original Answer:

In my case there are 2 issues getting Windows 10 Iot Core to boot on Raspberry PI 3B:

1. As the other answer by Whyan says, I have replaced my 32Gb SanDisk SD card with 16Gb SanDisk SD card.
2. I used the **RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661** from Microsoft IoT insider: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot

[image: enter code here]

3. After downloading the ISO file.

   - Rename iso file to .zip file
   - Extract .msi file from zip file.
   - Extract file from .msi file using 7-zip
     as shown in image

[image]

4. Insert your SD card in computer, now use Windows IoT dashboard to create your SD card boot using custom OS Build and choice `File_WindowsIoTRpi2Flash.ffu` from the files that you extracted from msi file.

[image]

5. When finished take your SD card and insert it in Rassperry PI 3B+ and it should boot.

Comment: Tried many solutions online and this worked for me. You provided a hard to find link to the working image of Windows 10 IoT Core Rpi B+

Comment: @Matt I agree it was very hard for me to understand all this, I have lost a lot of hours figuring out why 32Gb does not support, and finding the link. IT is a shame that in 2019 and Windows IoT can give headaches reminding me of year 2000 hardwares problems and windows 95 or NT

Answer (score 2):

It's the SD card, I was only ever able to get it to work reliably with a 32 gb sandisk SD card on 16299 and later. Even then the 32gb card has problems with the insider images, so try a different size and or manufacturer until you find one that works. When they started with windows iot (2015) only the 16gb size worked reliably, but now only the 32 gb seems to be reliable.