# Raspberry Pi3 B+ Windows IoT does not boot

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues, windows-iot

I am using Raspberry Pi3 Model B+ embedded card and I am trying to flash Windows IoT core.

I had some issues with it while it does not boot.

I followed the steps described here and used RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661 : 
[RPI3 B+ IOT](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/87503/109520)

But same problem occurs : stack in Rainbow screen.

I am using 16 GB Class 10 PLATINET micro SD. The SD is working fine with Raspbian.

Could anyone help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87530/33476) answer stating that only 32GB cards work with latest releases?

Comment: But in the accepted answer he said that he replaced his 32Gb SanDisk SD card with 16Gb SanDisk SD card.